# What is the difference between toGenericString and toString in java.lang.reflect.Field

Tags: java, tostring

```
package com.sample;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Demo {
    int i;
}

public class DifferenceGenericStringAndToString {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = Demo.class;
        Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            System.out.println(field.toGenericString());
            System.out.println(field.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output comes as :-**

> int com.sample.Demo.i
>
> int com.sample.Demo.i

Can anybody tell me that is there any difference between these methods?

Comment: Try declaring a generic field (like `List<String>`), and comparing the difference.

Comment: It merely epitomises the fact that type erasure was a boo boo.

Comment: it worked **@Andy Turner**, thanks. I never thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real answer here: when in doubt, read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#toGenericString()):

> Returns a string describing this Field, including its generic type. The format is the access modifiers for the field, if any, followed by the generic field type, followed by a space, followed by the fully-qualified name of the class declaring the field, followed by a period, followed by the name of the field.
>
> The modifiers are placed in canonical order as specified by "The Java Language Specification". This is public, protected or private first, and then other modifiers in the following order: static, final, transient, volatile.

Whereas, for `toString()` that says:

> Returns a string describing this Field. The format is the access modifiers for the field, if any, followed by the field type, followed by a space, followed by the fully-qualified name of the class declaring the field, followed by a period, followed by the name of the field.

And as **name** and **javadoc** give away: this has do to do with **generics**. So you might want to change your test code to, well use generics.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from javadoc :

> toGenericString()
>   Returns a string describing this Field, including its generic type.
>
> toString()
>   Returns a string describing this Field.

So if your Field has no generic type, there is no difference.

For mor info about generics, look here :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/